# Function always returns a 0

Tags: pascal

I'm a bit confused why the addition function always returns 0 no matter what combination of inputs I place. I've already checked if the user inputs are properly placed within the array I made and there are no problem at all within the input. Is the way I structured the function wrong by any means?

```
Program MathOperation;
uses crt;

type
inputArray = array [1..5] of real;
var
userChoice : integer;
inputValue : inputArray;

procedure userInputValues;
var
counter : integer = 0;
begin
    while counter<5 do
    begin
        write('>> Enter number [', counter + 1, ']: ');
        read(inputValue[counter]);
        counter := counter+1;
    end;
end;

function addOp:real;
var
addCtr : integer = 0;
sum : real = 0;
begin
     while addCtr<5 do
     begin
         sum := sum + inputValue[addCtr];
         addCtr := addCtr+1;
     end
end;
```

Comment: Please edit your q to include your complete program, down to and including the final `end.`  Also, where is `inputValue` declared and what it its definition?  You should really include an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function.

In Pascal, you specify the return value by assigning to the function name itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `AddOp` function always returns 0 because you never assign a value to its function result.  Somewhere in it, you should have a statement which is **guaranteed*** to execute and which is like this:

```
  AddOp := {whatever the correct value is}
```

Since you are apparently using FreePascal, you can use `Result` as an alias for the function result, as in

```
  Result := {whatever the correct value is}
```

*Actually, this is somewhat of an overstatement, because there may be more than one valid execution path through the code of the function, so the more general rule is that every valid execution path through the function should make the function return a value.